# Excel Pie Chart - Text Orientation

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an 18 sector pie chart and would like the label in each sector (within the chart, not outside it)  to be orientated towards the centre of the pie chart (like the spokes of a wheel). I'd say this option is probably not available but wonder if anyone has managed to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, this option is not available. A pie chart with 18 segments is pretty much useless from a data visualisation point of view. See here for a powerful demonstration: http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/08-21-07.pdf

You might be better off using a horizontal bar chart where the text can be placed inside the bars or as labels on the vertical axis.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is provided in VBA here, and worked perfectly:
https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50/vba/rotate-chart-label

Note that you have to manually format the data labels to be inside the chart, and you have to run the code every time you change the number of sectors in the pie chart

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thank you for you contribution, but whilst this may potentially answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential information here, and provide the link for reference. Please **edit your answer** to include that information. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that due to timing, my answer is irrelevant, but answering for other seekers of truth. Actually you can create as many segments as you want and orient the texts towards center automatically without using VBA or manual reformatting.

1. Create a Sunburst chart
2. Remove all columns in the data series but one

Downside: You cannot change the size of the donut's hole

Upside: You can insert another pie chart at the center of sunbirst chart to cover the hole and align with the segments

Voila